# Undefined Reference error when passing String as a parameter

Tags: c++, string, undefined

I have a cpp file which has the following prototype in class ABC:

```
    # include relevant header    
    void ABC::get_strikes(int atm_f, int exp, std::string index)
    {
        int sum =5;
    }
```

The function is declared in the corresponding hpp file:

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>

class ABC
{
    public:
    void get_strikes(int atm_f,int exp, std::string index);
}
```

I create the object file and call this function using the obj object of ABC class:

```
obj.get_strikes(3, 2, "Hello World");
```

This causes an undefined reference error:

```
undefined reference to `ABC::get_strikes(int, int, std::string)'
```

All other funtions in the class ABC are recognized correctly.
Note that removing the string as a parameter while leaving the other two solves the problem.
So is this some issue related to how strings are passed?

Comment: it should work, please provide a [mcve]

Comment: If the problem is that you didn't `#include <string>` where needed, you would have seen multiple error messages.   First there would be one or more error messages from the compiler, telling you that there is no such type as `string` (or `std::string`).      The "undefined" reference you report is emitted AFTER that, by the linker.    So you provided incomplete information here - the first error message emitted is often the most important in working out the cause of a problem.   And you only mentioned the LAST error message you saw.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply, but this is the only error message.

Comment: @MrOmnipotent Can you check if my answer solves your problem. Try to copy/paste the files from my answer and see if it compiles.

Comment: @MrOmnipotent In that case we need a [mre]. It would probably consist of 3 files (header and source file for `ABC`) and a source file that contains the `main`. Also the command you used to compile this will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you're not compiling the source file correctly. In this case if you're using ubuntu and gcc then you can use the following command to compile the below given program:

```
g++ main.cpp myfile.cpp -o program
```

Also i noticed that in your **cpp** file you've not included the corresponding header.

So don't forget to include the corresponding header in the cpp file as i have done in the program given below whose output can be seen [here](https://onlinegdb.com/Glvh_kje-).

**myfile.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
#include <string>//added this
class ABC
{
    public:
    void get_strikes(int atm_f,int exp, std::string index);
};
```

**myfile.cpp**

```
#include "myfile.h"//added this

void ABC::get_strikes(int atm_f, int exp, std::string index)
{
    int sum =5;
  
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "myfile.h"

int main()
{
  ABC obj;
  obj.get_strikes(3, 2, "Hello World");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I did this but to no avail. It still gives me an undefined reference error. I have include the header in the cpp file, I forgot to add here.

Comment: @MrOmnipotent Which compiler are you using? And what command do you use to compile your program?